# Hibernate Query Running Slow

Tags: oracle, performance, oracle-11g

I am currently facing a problem with a slow running Hibernate query that is being kicked off from a Java program. It is making a call to Oracle 11g at the back end.

This query is taking anything from 40-90 seconds the first time it is run. On subsequent executions however the query is returned in a fraction of the time (and I don't even see the database being hit, so assume that hibernate is caching it).

If I copy and paste the query from Enterprise Manager into a SQL client and run the very same query directly (even changing a few parameters) the query returns in a fraction of a second.

If I look at the performance tuning tab in EM I see that the time taken is primarily taken up with User I/O Waits (97.5%), and CPU (2.5%). Could this mean that the fetch size I am using in hibernate is configured at too small a value?

If there is any other information you might need to help me get to the bottom of this issue then please let me know.

=====

### Additional information:

We do have an index on the table and I can see that it is being used as part of the execution of the query, unfortunately it isn't very readable but I am not sure how else to include it:

```
Id  Operation   Name    Rows
(Estim)     Cost    Time
Active(s)   Start
Active  Execs   Rows
(Actual)    Read
Reqs    Read
Bytes   Mem
(Max)   Activity
(%)     Activity Detail
(# samples)
0   SELECT STATEMENT                        1                       
1   . FILTER                        1                       
2   .. HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER        2674    7223    1   +4  1   0           1M      
3   ... TABLE ACCESS FULL   TOTEM_EQ_EXPIRYCODES    475     4   1   +4  1   481                     
4   ... HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER       2674    7219    1   +4  1   0           399K        
5   .... TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID    TOTEM_EQ_UNDERLYINGS    1   2   1   +4  1   1                   
6   ..... INDEX UNIQUE SCAN     TOTEM_EQ_UND_PK     1   1   1   +4  1   1                   
7   .... NESTED LOOPS                       1                       
8   ..... NESTED LOOPS      2674    7216    42  +4  1   0                   
9   ...... TABLE ACCESS BY GLOBAL INDEX ROWID   EQUITIES_MONTHLY_INSTRUMENTS    2671    1871    45  +1  1   8438    3517    27MB        24.44   db file sequential read (11)
10  ....... INDEX RANGE SCAN    EQ_MON_INS_UNDERLYING_INDX  2671    12  42  +4  1   8438    27  216KB           
11  ...... PARTITION RANGE ITERATOR         1   2           8438                        
12  ....... INDEX RANGE SCAN    EQ_MON_RESULT_INSPT_UNQ     1   2   44  +2  8438    0   5403    42MB        75.56   Cpu (1)
db file sequential read (33)
13  ..... TABLE ACCESS BY LOCAL INDEX ROWID     EQUITIES_MONTHLY_RESULTS    1   3                   

Here are the Global stats:

Elapsed
Time(s)     Cpu
Time(s)     IO
Waits(s)    Fetch
Calls   Buffer
Gets    Read
Reqs    Read
Bytes
45  0.73    45  1   22980   9740    76MB
```

Comment: thanks deathApril this is not a DB to DB question though. We are accessing Oracle via Hibernate from a front end app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was to do with the index that was being selected as part of the query plan.

The query was accepting a range as part of its set of parameters. For reasons I won't go into now we were passing the range start and end date to be the same value.

When we were making the call directly we were hard coding these parameters and Oracle was deducing that they represented a single date, whereas when passing them via code the range was passed as bind variables.

This meant that Oracle selected to scan across all partitions in one case, and against a specific partition in the other.

We ultimately fixed the query by passing in just a single date parameter, since we realised we didn't need a range!

A rather peculiar situation admittedly!

Answer (score -1):

Have you try to create indexes on which you are creating query.
I had a similar issue with my project, in which i have to fetch a list of users as per search criteria of firstname , lastname and email_address, 
To fetch the specific set of users from total **1,000,000 users**, hibernate is taking aroung **300 seconds** .
But after  **creating indexes of firstname , lastname and email_address** ,it takes only 2-3 seconds for same number of users as previous.

Even one more strange thing i have notice with hibernate, take example of Class User

```
Class User
{ 
    ...
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String email;
    ...
}
```

if i create a search criteria for User and adding restriction of email containing "gmail.com" , its gave me result in around 10 secs, result contains approximate 10,000 users.
But if i write a HQL query for same conditions which i have added in hibernate criteria, its gave me result in around 2-3 seconds.

So what i have notice is HQL are much faster then criteria.
This can be wrong , but i am sharing my personal experience.

I hope this will help you to solve performance issue.

Comment: fetch size comes into picture if your data size is large.For small/medium size it doesnot have much impact.

Comment: The data size does seem to be large so maybe the fetch size is the issue - from what I can see in the "Global Stats" posted above there are 76MB returned...